# Continuous Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

When studying Bernoulli random variables the following formula is commonly used: $$\Pr(X=x)={n\choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\,,$$ where $p$ is the probability of a success. Further questions ask to graph the distributions such as the question:

[image: Question]

My question is can you construct a continuous bernoulli distribution with the gamma function to derive a continuous ${n\choose x}$ and what is the applications of this continuous choose function in combinatorics?
$${n\choose r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(n-r)}$$

Comment: I believe you're thinking of a *binomial* distribution. A Bernoulli distribution would take values on $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is the [Beta Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) whose probability density function, for strictly positive shape parameters, $\alpha,\beta$, is: $$Y\sim\mathcal{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)\iff f_{\small Y}(y)=\dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\,\Gamma(\beta)}y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant y\leqslant 1}$$

Which provides a family of prior probability distributions for binomial distributions in Bayesian inference.

Comment: Note in particular that $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$, so that ratio of Gammas is $(\alpha+\beta-1)\binom{\alpha+\beta-2}{\alpha-1}$.